# Nodejs and Sequelize Limitations regarding creating dynamic models

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've a simple question related to my scenario. I've a react frontend where admin have a form to define it's own sign up form for the users.

- Admin will send a set of fields with it's data types
- Backend NodeJs will take those fields and run some script/function to create table in a database with the data types accordingly
- It also needs to create a model for the respective table dynamically
  I'm just finding a way to get it done. Any alternate solution is welcomed or any suggestions to refine my scenario?
  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can just map all indicated fields into field definitions for Sequielize like:

```js
    fieldName: {
        field: 'field_name',
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
```

and call `sequelize.define` which will return you a Sequilize model that you can use to execute queries:

```js
// NOTE "sequelize" should be an instance of Sequelize, i.e. an existing connection.
function registerModel(tableName, modelName, fields) {
  const model = sequelize.define(modelName, {
    ...fields
  }, {
    tableName: tableName,
    timestamps: false,
  });
  return model;
}
```

Register a new model:

```js
const fields = [{
    fieldName: {
        field: 'field_name',
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
}]
const newModel = registerModel('some_table', 'someModel', fields);
```

Use the registered model:

```js
  const items = await newModel.findAll({
    where: {
      // some conditions
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks man for your quick response . Let me try this strategy today